# Unity CustomEditor - модифицировать отображение массива

Tags: c#, unity3d, customeditor

Можно ли как-то вместо вот этого текста написать что-то своё?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот [тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-the-name-of-list-elements-in-the-inspector.448910/) несколько вариантов

Comment: а для чего? Учитывая что это никак не влияет на геймплей

Comment: Лично мне кажется что если тебе хочется это переименовать, то вероятнее всего у тебя что-то не так с кодом. Потому что массив в таком случае сохраняет не список однородных сущностей, а отдельные по своей логике сущности одного типа.

Comment: это типа для геймдизайнеров оснаска. Там должно быть просто максимально наглядно, и тут было бы довольно удобно.